# Apache http/https non-www to ww url redirection

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, apache2

I've got a problem with apache configuration (linux distro).
I want to redirect typed URLs (in browser):

`domain.com`
`www.domain.com`
`http://domain.com`
`http://www.domain.com`
`https://domain.com`

to only one: **https://www.domain.com**
What should I do in .htaccess file?
Notice that I've got only one certificate. Exactly for www.domain.com

Thank you in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Please note you can use the `example.com`, `example.net` and `example.org` names for examples and the like. They're reserved for that precise purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The four conditions are two groups of disjunct conditions where the first condition of each group tests for a missing `www.` and the non-HTTPS respectively. Each second condition of the groups are just to get the part of the HTTP host without the leading `www.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !=www.domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}       !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=permanent,L]
```

In any case, you only have one virtual host so you won't be able to skip the browser warning about the certificate when entering `https://domain.com`.

Comment: Thank you for answers guys! :) Alvaro - your solution works for me perfect! Once again - thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answers you find useful.